# Joomla has no CiviReport permissioning, so how can I limit reports to individual users?

Tags: joomla, civireport, permissions

Welp, after the disappointing realization from [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/33959/how-to-set-permissions-on-individual-civireports-permission-options-not-shown) -- that unlike the Drupal and Wordpress implementations, CiviCRM in Joomla does NOT include permissioning for individual CiviReports -- I'm now trying to figure out the best way to approximate this functionality in Joomla.  I have groups of Joomla users that should only be able to see individual reports, and apparently I can't do this with the default implementation.

Some thoughts:

1. limit the reports' menu items by Joomla/CiviCRM permission. But there are no purpose-built permissions for this. Is it possible to create custom Joomla permissions for CiviCRM?  Or would I have to pick some existing permission I'm not really "using" and assign it to each Joomla group?
2. Is it possible to intercept each report compilation, or even the navigation menu building, somewhere in the CiviCRM code with a Joomla permissions/group check?

I know both of these are kludgey ideas, but I'm really stuck without this feature that I thought was standard in all CiviCRM versions.  Suggestions incredibly welcome.

Comment: I just posted something that might be worth trying on the other question.

Comment: Well worth trying, Demerit, thanks. But it doesn't work, so I'm still looking for solutions.